# Why do i get a command prompt when i launch my app C#

Tags: c#

My code is completely normal and it actually don't relate a command prompt in any way
here's my Form1_Load code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Hide();
    this.handlers = default(DiscordRpc.EventHandlers);
    DiscordRpc.Initialize(clientID, ref this.handlers, true, null);
    presence.state = "hi'";
    presence.largeImageKey = "discord";
    presence.largeImageText = "DiscordRP";
    DiscordRpc.UpdatePresence(ref this.presence);

    // dam, a cuttttttt ;))

    if (Settings.Default.puddeeExclusive == false)
    {
        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
        notifyIcon2.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
        notifyIcon2.Visible = true;
    }
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        string update = client.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/example");
        string changes = client.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/example");
        string ver = client.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/example");
        // ^^ Up here downloads the main HTML Code AKA raw text in pastebin.
        if (update == "UPDATE")
        { // If the version is the same of the string update well that means it will update the version it is (It changes every update).
          
            MessageBox.Show("New Update Came!", "Update", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            if(MessageBox.Show(changes, "Improvements :", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Process.Start("https://github.com/User/Example/Releases");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Update", "Message");
            }
        }
    }
```

But i get a command prompt once i launch it, it's a system tray program that doesn't have a main window.

Comment: A note, it actually checks for updates and so it updates it if the user allowed, if denied it will mention that older versions can't update since the pastebin link is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I just realised that there's an error in the Program.cs where my namespace was different so i fixed it and now there's no command prompt.
So the question wasn't that important since i answered it less than 5 minutes later.